# Tomcat server and Jenkins conflict port

Tags: jenkins, tomcat

I have installed Jenkins and tomcat on my pc, I have changed the port number of tomcat to 8081, since Jenkins has its default port number 8080. When I open browser and type "localhost:8081", tomcat server page is not opening.

Answer (score 1):

Check your firewall settings to be sure 8081 is open.
Is the tomcat server running?